# Non-upper bounds without excluded middle

Tags: logic, nonclassical-logic, constructive-mathematics

Motivated by [an earlier question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/639927/upper-bound-of-a-set-equivalence-problem/639963), I'm curious if we can prove the following statement without the law of excluded middle:

> Let $E$ be a set of real numbers. A number $x$ is said to be an *upper bound* for $E$ if $e\leq x$ for all $e\in E$. Prove that $y$ is not an upper bound for $E$ if and only if there exists $e\in E$ such that $e > y$.

To prove the statement, it seems necessary to invert a quantifier and an order relation, and both steps feel dubious. I don't have a reference work, but Wikipedia indicates that [trichotomy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trichotomy_(mathematics)) isn't guaranteed in intuitionistic logic, and [this bit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intuitionistic_logic#Non-interdefinability_of_operators) doesn't mention any allowed implication of the form $\neg(\forall e \phi(e))\to(\bullet)$. So:

1. Is only one direction of the statement true/provable without excluded middle?
2. Is there a standard way to weaken the statement so that the weaker version holds in both directions?
3. What if we replace the real numbers with a simpler set, like the rational numbers or integers?

My question isn't necessarily limited to intuitionistic logic. Feel free to answer for your favorite logical system!

Comment: Have you seen : Errett Bishop & Douglas Bridges, *Constructive Analysis* (1985), pag.36 ?

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA Thanks, I have now! Continuing to page 37, Proposition 4.3 states: "Let $A$ be a nonvoid set of real numbers that is bounded above. Then $\sup A$ exists if and only if for all $x,y$ in $\mathbb R$ with $x<y$, either $y$ is an upper bound of $A$ or there exists $a$ in $A$ with $x<a$." From this, I suppose it follows that if $E$ is nonvoid and has a supremum, then the statement I asked about is true for $E$. But the converse presumably doesn't hold. I wonder if there's a nice characterization of those sets $E$ for which my statement is true?

Comment: Sorry, but I don't know about "characterization of those sets E for which ...". About the proof in your question, if you deny the condition of the definition [$\forall e (e \in E \rightarrow e \le x)$, where $x = ub(E)$] you get in *classical logic* : $\exists e (e \in E \land e < y)$ but a step in the proof is not admissible *intuitionistically*: where going from $\lnot (p \rightarrow q)$ i.e. $\lnot (\lnot p \lor q)$, to $(\lnot \lnot p \land q)$; you cannot remove the double negation ... It does not means that you cannot try other ways.

Comment: There is a misprint in the last formula; please read it as $(\lnot \lnot p \land \lnot q)$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The principle "if $a$ is not an upper bound for $E$, then there is an element of $E$ that is greater than $a$" is expressed formally as 
$$
\lnot [ (\forall x \in E) ( x < a \lor x = a) ]  \to (\exists x \in E)(a < x).
$$

This principle is not provable in the standard formal system called "intuitionistic first-order predicate logic" which I will call IFOL. In fact, even the weaker formula
$$
(1) \quad \lnot [ ( \forall x) ( x < a \lor x = a)] \to (\exists x)(a < x) 
$$
is not provable in IFOL from the axioms of a linear order (reflexivity, antisymmetry, and transitivity of $<$). I want to focus on that weaker principle (1), because it avoids any unnecessary distractions with sets. So we work in a theory that has only one type of object, and only two binary relations: equality and a linear order $<$.

My claim is that (1) is not provable in IFOL from the axioms of a linear ordering. The way to prove this, as might be expected, is to produce a countermodel. But this must necessarily be a *nonclassical* countermodel, because principle (1) is provable from the axioms of a linear order in classical logic.  Before I describe a formal countermodel, let me describe the intuition behind it.

#### Intuition

The intuition *why* principle (1) is not provable in IFOL is related to the different relationship between universal and existential quantifiers in constructive logic. It also relates to an intuition in constructive logic that "more elements may appear at any time". In classical logic, we treat $\forall$ and $\exists$ as dual to each other. In constructive systems, it is often better to view $\forall$ as *making a promise* and $\exists$ as *producing a witness*:

- $(\forall x)[x < a \lor x = a]$ can be viewed as a promise that, whenever we find another element $x$, it will be equal to $a$ or less than $a$.
- $(\exists x)[a < x]$ asserts that we already have a specific witness $x_0$ with $a < x_0$.

Imagine I am constructing a model, adding elements one at a time, and I have not yet made up my mind whether I want $a$ to be an upper bound. We can view $\lnot (\forall x)[x = a \lor x < a]$ as saying that, although $a$ might be an upper bound for the elements I have already added, I am not willing to promise that $a$ will be an upper bound for all elements I might add later. Maybe $a$ will end up as an upper bound, maybe not. But $(\exists x)[a < x]$ means I have already chosen an element to be less than $a$.

I can certainly reserve the right to later add an element larger than $a$, without adding that element at the present time: formalizing this situation gives a model in which principle (1) fails.

#### Formal countermodel

One type of nonclassical model is called a *Kripke frame*; these are briefly described at [the Stanford Encyclopedia article](http://plato.stanford.edu/entries/logic-intuitionistic/#KriSemForIntLog) on intuitionistic logic.  It is important to remember that "intuitionistic logic" here means the particular formal deductive system IFOL.

Now, assuming some familiarity with Kripke frames: the desired Kripke frame has just two nodes, $p$ and $p'$. In node $p$ we have the linear ordering with just one element $a$. In node $p'$ we have the linear ordering with two elements $a,b$ and $a < b$.  Node $p$ does not force that $a$ is an upper bound, in fact $p$ forces $\lnot [ (\forall x)(x < a \lor x = a)]$. But $p$ does not force any witness for $(\exists x)[a < x]$. So node $p$ does not force formula (1). Because a formula is provable in IFOL if and only if it is forced by every node of every Kripke frame, principle (1) is not provable in intuitionistic logic.

#### Answers to the remaining parts of the question

The converse of (1) is provable in IFOL.

One way to weaken (1) is to use a translation that maps provable formula of classical first-order logic to classically equivalent formulas provable in IFOL. The [double-negation translations](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-negation_translation) do this, for example. These add enough additional double-negations to the formula to make it intuitionistically provable, while preserving classical equivalence.

Comment: I should have also said: the small Kripke frame in my answer does force $(\forall x,y)[x=y\lor x < y \lor y < x]$ as well as the reflexivity, antisymmetry, and transitivity of $<$. And, of course, $a$ and $b$ satisfy $a \not = b$ in $p'$.

Comment: I think there are some problems with this answer, or rather its relation to the question.  The statements you show are unprovable do not match the constructive formalization of $\geq$ and "is not an upper bound".   In constructive analysis $x \geq E$ means $x > E - e$ for all positive rational $e$, which is also the natural definition when $E$ is a set of reals.   Likewise, "is not an upper bound of $E$" would not be defined as the negation of "is an upper bound of $E$" but as "is less than some element of $E$".   Also, IFOL+(partial order axioms) is much weaker than constructive order theory.

Comment: As a concrete example, I think the statement "$\neg(x=y) \implies ((x<y) \vee (x>y))$" holds under Bishop's definitions of real numbers and the equality and order relations.   But the system you wrote down cannot prove that even classically, because it is a theory of partial orders.

Answer (score 0):

Constructively, negations are superfluous. Ordinarily one would give a positive definition of negative concepts like "is not an upper bound" and the natural definition in this case would turn the statement under discussion into a tautology.   It would assert that $A \leftrightarrow B$, where $A$ was previously defined to be true if and only if $B$ holds.

Comment: I'll elaborate the answer later, but note that the natural constructive definition of "$y$ is not an upper bound of $E$" is "there exists an element $e \in E$ such that $e > y$".   This makes the implication in the question trivially true by definition.   If the intent was to analyze the (constructively irrelevant) question of whether the same conclusion is implied by "not ($y$ is an upper bound of $E$)" then the definitions of upper bound and $\geq$ will also be different from the classical one, so that the situation is not really addressed by the accepted answer.